# finding correct xpath for a table without an id

Tags: html, r, xpath

I am following a tutorial on R-Bloggers [using rvest to scrape table](https://www.r-bloggers.com/using-rvest-to-scrape-an-html-table/). I think I have the wrong column id value, but I don't understand how to get the correct one. Can someone explain what value I should use, and why?

As @hrbrmstr points out this is against the WSJ terms of service, however the answer is useful for those who face a similar issue with a different webpage.

```
library("rvest")
interest<-url("http://online.wsj.com/mdc/public/page/2_3020-libor.html")%>%read_html()%>%html_nodes(xpath='//*[@id="column0"]/table[1]') %>% html_table()
```

The structure returns is an empty list.

Comment: You're in violation of several points in section 8 of the WSJ Terms of Service. Please cease trying to bring others in to your attempts at encouraging legal proceedings and/or data stealing. Just b/c you can do something doesn't make it legal or ethical to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me it is usual a trial and error to find the correct table.  In this case, the third table is what you are looking for:

```
library("rvest")
page<-url("http://online.wsj.com/mdc/public/page/2_3020-libor.html")%>%read_html()
tables<-html_nodes(page, "table") 
html_table(tables[3])
```

Instead of using the xpath, I just parse out the "table" tag and looked at each table to locate the correct one.  The piping command is handy but it makes it harder to debug when something goes wrong.